# Pandas JSON data parsing projection

Tags: python, json, pandas

It seems to me that it would be imminently useful for pandas to support the idea of projection (omitting or selecting columns) during data parsing.

Many JSON datasets I find have a ton of extraneous fields I don't need, or I need to parse a specific field in the nested structure.

What I do currently is pipe through `jq` to create a file that contains only the fields I need. This becomes the "cleaned" file.

I would prefer a method where I didn't have to create a new cleaned file every time I want to look at a particular facet or set of facets, but I could instead tell pandas to load the JSON path `.data.interesting` and only project fields: `A B C`.

As an example:

```
{
 "data": {
   "not interesting": ["milk", "yogurt", "dirt"],
   "interesting": [{ "A": "moonlanding", "B": "1956", "C": 100000, "D": "meh" }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like there's no easy way to do it on load, but if you're okay with doing it immediately after...

```
# drop by index
df.drop(df.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1, inplace=True)

# drop by name
df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Sigh, that's the conclusion I had come to as well.

Comment: Do you get a large performance hit by not omitting those columns?

Comment: Actually wait, does `usecols` solve your problem?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: "Using this parameter results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage." If it's performance benefits you want, that will give it to you. @Breedly